# Do Content-Security-Policy errors affect SEO rankings?

Tags: seo, content-security-policy

There is a website that allows users to post content and embed images from external links. This website has a Content-Security-Policy that allows only a small list of other websites in img-src.

If a user embeds an image from a URL that is not whitelisted and the browser generates a CSP violation error, will that have any impact on SEO ranking?

I do understand that a better practice would probably be to disallow posting embedded images from non-whitelisted URLs in the first place, but please assume that this is not an option.